# Identify metrics names that are exceeding their limits

Tags: prometheus, metrics, promql, prometheus-alertmanager

I want to catch when AWS limits are exceeded.

Currently I export metrics using https://github.com/jantman/awslimitchecker that look like:

```
# HELP vpc_vpcs
# TYPE vpc_vpcs gauge
vpc_vpcs{region="us-east-1",type="limit"} 5.0
vpc_vpcs{region="us-east-1",type="current"} 6.0
# HELP vpc_virtual_private_gateways
# TYPE vpc_virtual_private_gateways gauge
vpc_virtual_private_gateways{region="us-east-1",type="limit"} 5.0
vpc_virtual_private_gateways{region="us-east-1",type="current"} 0.0
```

https://github.com/kaihendry/debugprom/blob/main/exportme/metrics.prom

I want to come up with a PromQL query and alert to catch all metric **names** that are exceeding their limit (BONUS: or will do in future using [predict_linear](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#predict_linear)). I've tried summing, I've tried queries like `{job="node-exporter", type="current"} > {job="node-exporter", type="limit"}`, but they don't work.

What am I missing please?

Answer (score 0):

What version of that exporter are you using? example metrics in the link you provided look like this in master branch:

```
# HELP aws_limit Usage limit once hit requires an AWS support request
# TYPE aws_limit gauge
aws_limit{region="us-east-1",type="vpcs"} 5
aws_limit{region="us-east-1",type="vpcs-gateway"} 5
# HELP aws_current Current usage level
# TYPE aws_current gauge
aws_current{region="us-east-1",type="vpcs"} 6
aws_current{region="us-east-1",type="vpcs-gateway"} 0
```

Which makes querying very easy, since now the subject is already a label and you don't need to catch the metric name (`__name__` basically) for your alert.

So alert expressions would be:

```
aws_current >= on(type, region) (aws_limit * 0.8)
```